# Scrapy spider is not working

Tags: python, scrapy

Since nothing so far is working I started a new project with

```
python scrapy-ctl.py startproject Nu
```

I followed the tutorial exactly, and created the folders, and a new spider

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item
from Nu.items import NuItem
from urls import u

class NuSpider(CrawlSpider):
    domain_name = "wcase"
    start_urls = ['http://www.whitecase.com/aabbas/']

    names = hxs.select('//td[@class="altRow"][1]/a/@href').re('/.a\w+')

    u = names.pop()

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(u, )), callback='parse_item'),)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = Item()
        item['school'] = hxs.select('//td[@class="mainColumnTDa"]').re('(?<=(JD,\s))(.*?)(\d+)')
        return item

SPIDER = NuSpider()
```

and when I run

```
C:\Python26\Scripts\Nu>python scrapy-ctl.py crawl wcase
```

I get

```
[Nu] ERROR: Could not find spider for domain: wcase
```

The other spiders at least are recognized by Scrapy, this one is not. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you provide a link to the tutorial (if it's online) ? would be an interesting read :)

Comment: Yes, here's the link to the CrawlSpider example: http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example

Answer (score 6):

Please also check the version of scrapy. The latest version uses "name" instead of "domain_name" attribute to uniquely identify a spider.

Answer (score 3):

Have you included the spider in `SPIDER_MODULES` list in your scrapy_settings.py?

It's not written in the tutorial anywhere that you should to this, but you do have to.

Comment: This is included when project is created:

SPIDER_MODULES = ['Nu.spiders']

But I don't know if I need to add the domain_name = 'wcase' as well?

the spider is now running but it is just scanning the initial url, it doesn't go to allowed links. See my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809817/scrapy-sgmllinkextractor-question

Answer (score 3):

These two lines look like they're causing trouble:

```
u = names.pop()

rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(u, )), callback='parse_item'),)
```

- Only one rule will be followed each time the script is run. Consider creating a rule for each URL.
- You haven't created a `parse_item` callback, which means that the rule does nothing. The only callback you've defined is `parse`, which changes the default behaviour of the spider.

Also, here are some things that will be worth looking into.

- `CrawlSpider` doesn't like having its default `parse` method overloaded. Search for `parse_start_url` in the documentation or the docstrings. You'll see that this is the preferred way to override the default `parse` method for your starting URLs.
- `NuSpider.hxs` is called before it's defined.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have syntax errors there. The `name = hxs...` will not work because you don't get defined before the `hxs` object.

Try running `python yourproject/spiders/domain.py` to get syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the `parse` method, instead of implementing a new `parse_item` method.