# Scrape CrawlSpider AttributeError '_rules'

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the website of a prominent UK retailer but I am facing an issue with my CrawlSpider - I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'NlCrawlerSpider' object has no attribute '_rules'

I used the example [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/web-scraping-and-crawling-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/) to convert my regular spider into a crawl spider; I have also played around with the syntax for the Rules as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809817/scrapy-sgmllinkextractor-question) but end up with the same error msg. All your help would be much appreciated - thank you in advance!

```
# Scrapy
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

# Other Packages
import time
from datetime import date
from selenium import webdriver


class NlCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'nl_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['newlook.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/c/uk-womens-clothing?comp=NavigationBar%7Cmn%7Cwomens%7Cclothing#/?q=:relevance&page=1&sort=relevance&content=false']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'\?q=:relevance&page=[1-130]&sort=relevance&content=false', ), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
    self.driver.set_window_size(800,600)
    time.sleep(2)

def parse_item(self, response):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(2)


    # Collect products
    products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('plp-item ng-scope')

    # Iterate over products; extract data and append individual features to NlScrapeItem
    for item in products:

        # Pull features
        desc = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-item__name link--nounderline ng-binding').text
        href = item.find_element_by_class_name('plp-carousel__img-link ng-scope').get_attribute('href')

        # Generate a product identifier
        identifier = href.split('/p/')[1].split('?comp')[0]
        identifier = int(identifier)

        # datetime
        dt = date.today()
        dt = dt.isoformat()

        # Price Symbol removal and integer conversion
        try:
            priceString = item.find_element_by_class_name('price ng-binding').text
        except:
            priceString = item.find_element_by_class_name('price price--previous-price product-item__price--previous-price ng-binding ng-scope').text
        priceInt = priceString.split('£')[1]
        originalPrice = float(priceInt)

        # discountedPrice Logic
        try:
            discountedPriceString = item.find_element_by_class_name('price ng-binding price--marked-down').text
            discountedPriceInt = discountedPriceString.split('£')[1]
            discountedPrice = float(discountedPriceInt)
        except:
            discountedPrice = 'N/A'

        # NlScrapeItem
        item = NlScrapeItem()

        # Append product to NlScrapeItem
        item['identifier'] = identifier
        item['href'] = href
        item['description'] = desc
        item['originalPrice'] = originalPrice
        item['discountedPrice'] = discountedPrice
        item['firstSighted'] = dt
        item['lastSighted'] = dt

        yield item
```

Additions:
So I tried to ignore the idea of using a crawlSpider and follow @jabargas thinking - see below:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
    self.driver.set_window_size(800,600)

def start_requests(self):
    n = 5
    urls= []
    for pageNumber in range(1,n):
            url = 'http://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/c/uk-womens-clothing?comp=NavigationBar%%7Cmn%%7Cwomens%%7Cclothing#/?q=:relevance&page=%d&sort=relevance&content=false' % pageNumber
            urls.append(url)

    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


def parse(self, response):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(2)


    # Collect products
    products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('plp-item ng-scope')

    # Iterate over products; extract data and append individual features to NlScrapeItem
    for item in products:

        # Pull features
        desc = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-item__name link--nounderline ng-binding').text
        href = item.find_element_by_class_name('plp-carousel__img-link ng-scope').get_attribute('href')

        # Generate a product identifier
        identifier = href.split('/p/')[1].split('?comp')[0]
        identifier = int(identifier)

        # datetime
        dt = date.today()
        dt = dt.isoformat()

        # Price Symbol removal and integer conversion
        try:
            priceString = item.find_element_by_class_name('price ng-binding').text
        except:
            priceString = item.find_element_by_class_name('price price--previous-price product-item__price--previous-price ng-binding ng-scope').text
        priceInt = priceString.split('£')[1]
        originalPrice = float(priceInt)

        # discountedPrice Logic
        try:
            discountedPriceString = item.find_element_by_class_name('price ng-binding price--marked-down').text
            discountedPriceInt = discountedPriceString.split('£')[1]
            discountedPrice = float(discountedPriceInt)
        except:
            discountedPrice = 'N/A'

        # NlScrapeItem
        item = NlScrapeItem()

        # Append product to NlScrapeItem
        item['identifier'] = identifier
        item['href'] = href
        item['description'] = desc
        item['originalPrice'] = originalPrice
        item['discountedPrice'] = discountedPrice
        item['firstSighted'] = dt
        item['lastSighted'] = dt

        yield item
```

Unfortunately no luck: it pulls details for 48 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this to scrape till page n:

```
start_urls = ['http://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/c/uk-womens-clothing?comp=NavigationBar%%7Cmn%%7Cwomens%%7Cclothing#/?q=:relevance&page=%d&sort=relevance&content=false' % page_number' for page_number in range(1,n)]
```

where n is the last page + 1

Or you could use scrapy pagination - get the link to the next page and follow it as you can find [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

Comment: thanks for reaching out! I'm actually fine with just the search results - my understanding was that it will go through pages 1 to 130 as in: 'allow=r'\?q=:relevance&page=[1-130]&sort=relevance&content=false', )'. I'm keen to hear your thoughts! Philipp

Comment: ah.. If that's just what you want, there's actually no need to use Rules or CrawlSpider to simplify things for you. You could just modify the url, make a Request for each, then scrape accordingly :)

Comment: I presume you mean as in: (that'd require me to manually write out 130 urls or what are you thinking of?)                                                                         'def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)'

Comment: Ok - thanks for the above - but how do I actually make the callback 'parse' for every individual page then. Please don't take this the wrong way but I think we are introducing a new set of issues this way - although I might just be ignorant :-)

Comment: Well, what you said could be a possible solution as well. If you know the last page, you can make a list comprehension for the start_urls with that.

Comment: I just removed my first answer, I gave it as a guide on what you can do. Sorry if it confused you. You also have to escape the percent for the url so that it could be formatted correctly.

Comment: that sounds great - let me try!

Comment: edited to escape the %. Should be working now, tested that the list is correct.

Comment: see my addition to the original question above - I tested the url generation function in the shell and it worked but not when implemented as part of the scraper

Comment: just looked at the website, and here's what I found out: the website populates the search page with json. That means, you don't have to do the pagination thingy. If you start at page 100+ something, you would notice that you would load all the items. So, you could just set the page at a high number and scrape from there. To check it, just use your normal browser for now and set the page to 100+ and check 'Showing xxx of xxxx items'

Answer (score 2):

Another possible issue is that you have not added super constructor in your **init** method.

add "super(MySpider, self).**init**(*a, **kw)" for it.

I got the same issue and fixed it by that.

so **init** should look like follows

```
def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
    super(MySpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
    //your initializations
```