# Scrapy Could not find spider Error

Tags: python, dns, scrapy

I have been trying to get a simple spider to run with scrapy, but keep getting the error:

`Could not find spider for domain:stackexchange.com`

when I run the code with the expression `scrapy-ctl.py crawl stackexchange.com`. The spider is as follow:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from __future__ import absolute_import


class StackExchangeSpider(BaseSpider):
    domain_name = "stackexchange.com"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.stackexchange.com/",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)

SPIDER = StackExchangeSpider()`
```

Another person posted almost the exact same problem months ago but did not say how they fixed it, [Scrapy spider is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806990/scrapy-spider-is-not-working) 
I have been following the turtorial exactly at http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/tutorial.html, and cannot figure out why it is not working.

When I run this code in eclipse I get the error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Documents\dmoz\stackexchange\stackexchange\spiders\stackexchange_spider.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
ImportError: No module named scrapy.spider`

I cannot figure out why it is not finding the base Spider module. Does my spider have to be saved in the scripts directory?

Comment: My spider does not have any rule statements in it so I do not think that applies. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Do you get the same error when using the DmozSpider defined in the tutorial?

Comment: I have not tried it with dmoz as the domain. all I really did was change the site it crawls.

Comment: Where did you place the code posted above? I suspect it is not being found in the project/spiders directory, and it is not getting imported. If it was, you'd get an error saying that the `from __future__ import absolute_import` line has to come before the other import line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try running `python yourproject/spiders/domain.py` to see if there are any syntax error. I don't think you should enable absolute import as scrapy relies on relatives imports.

Comment: It says it cannot find tbe scrapy.spider module

Comment: ya, first issue says `Could not find spider for domain:stackexchange.com` which is a scrapy message, therefore scrapy module loads correctly. And the latter issue is related to eclipse and pythonpath.

Comment: Problem fixed. Reinstalled on another computer. Must have had files misplaced or it installed wrong.